# jupyter lab reopen previous closed/shutdown notebook

Tags: jupyter-lab

After closing jupyter lab and re-launching jupyter lab, it always opens a notebook that was shutdown in previous session. How do I properly remove that notebook from re-opening on every launch?

`jupyter lab --version #1.2.15`

Comment: any notebook created in Jupyter lab gets auto saved and by default it autoloads the previous session which was last worked upon. Even your ```untitled``` notebooks gets autosaved, you can always check in the path where it is installed

Answer (score 1):

any notebook created in Jupyter lab gets auto saved and by default it autoloads the previous session which was last worked upon. Even your untitled notebooks gets autosaved, you can always check in the path where it is installed

Answer (score 0):

[right click the kernal and there ill be a delete option or use the close button (x) right on top]